# Cygwin and PHPUnit: Could not open input file: /cygdrive/c/xampp/php/phpunit

Tags: cygwin, phpunit

Is there a way to run PHPUnit from Cygwin? Everytime I run PHPUnit I get this error:

```
Could not open input file: /cygdrive/c/xampp/php/phpunit
```

I am trying to run my unit tests in my Zend Framework App. I am trying to use Cygwin because I am more familiar with *Nix commands (I'm no expert though) rather than Windows.

Thanks,
Wenbert

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am having the same problem, I can't get "phpunit" to work by itself, I am using Wamp.

However, I was able to run "phpunit.bat" and it worked for me.

Still can't get the ANSI colors to show up though :(

Comment: I was having problems showing colours as well. Adding `export ConEmuANSI=ON` to `~/.bashrc` solved the problem.

Answer (score 23):

same problem here, solved it by an alias added to ~/.bash_profile

> alias phpunit="/cygdrive/c/xampp/php/php C:/xampp/php/phpunit"

Comment: Finally I found the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I really don't like how hacky it is. Do you have any idea why it's necessary to call both paths absolutely in order to run a PHP program under Cygwin? The same behaviour applies to the WP-CLI tools provided by Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Does /cygdrive/c/xampp/php/phpunit exist?  If so what are the permissions on the file?

Try

```
ls -l /cygdrive/c/xampp/php/phpunit
```

Comment: I chmod the file to 777. Here are the results of the ls -l

$ ls -la /cygdrive/c/xampp/php/phpunit
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 Administrators None 2142 2010-02-12 16:08 /cygdrive/c/xampp/php/phpunit

Answer (score -1):

Let's use phpunit as dependency and in folder above vendor try:

```
ln -s vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit phpunit
```

It will create for you a symbolic link to real path of phpunit

Answer (score -1):

You could just directly call it by using Windows path in Cygwin:

```
C:/xampp/php/phpunit --version
```

> So you could set an alias for `~/.bash_profile`:
>
> ```
> alias phpunit="C:/xampp/php/phpunit"
> ```