# Cygwin issue when trying to run phpunit within Yii2

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii2, phpunit, cygwin

I'm trying to run `phpunit` within a Yii2 basic installation but whenever I run `php vendor/bin/phpunit` from the command line I get this output:

**Note:** I am on Windows 7.

```
dir=$(d=${0%[/\\]*}; cd "$d"; cd "../phpunit/phpunit" && pwd)

# See if we are running in Cygwin by checking for cygpath program
if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        # Cygwin paths start with /cygdrive/ which will break windows PHP,
        # so we need to translate the dir path to windows format. However
        # we could be using cygwin PHP which does not require this, so we
        # test if the path to PHP starts with /cygdrive/ rather than /usr/bin
        if [[ $(which php) == /cygdrive/* ]]; then
                dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
        fi
fi

dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g')
"${dir}/phpunit" "$@"
```

Can anyone advise what the issue is here? I haven't used `phpunit` before so unsure what is happening.

Comment: Have you checked [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266661/cygwin-and-phpunit-could-not-open-input-file-cygdrive-c-xampp-php-phpunit)?

Comment: @Bizley Thanks, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, it was an obvious solution:

File `vendor/bin/phpunit` is not a PHP script, but a shell script.

Remove `php` from the start and simply run `vendor/bin/phpunit`.

[Source](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2365#issuecomment-261733610).

Comment: Hello Brett,
I have tried command without PHP, but with out it PHP extended class is not finding in call.

here is error: Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in \tests\ProgrammerControllerTest.php on line 8

Comment: @Jaymin I'm not 100% sure I follow your problem - perhaps you could create a new question with more info?

Comment: removing php I am getting `'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command`, and with php it prints what 's inside that file the shell script you mentioned. As mentioned in the question it simply output the script

Answer (score 0):

Removing php from command I am getting `'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command`, and with php it prints what 's inside that file the shell script you mentioned. As mentioned in the question it simply output the script

To fix this

- Add php to path as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307548/how-to-access-php-with-the-command-line-on-windows)

Or

- For temporary use, try this: (benefit for use npm or composer)
  `SET PATH=c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.29\;%PATH%`